# Can't import eclipse project in android studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I am trying to import eclipse project in Android Studio using http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html
Android Studio Version 0.4.2

Steps I followed:

1. Exported Eclipse project using "Generate Gradle build files"
2. Import Project in Android Studio and selected the build.gradle file.

Now when I open any layout file in Android Studio it gives error:

> "Rendering Problems No Android SDK found. Please configure an Android
>   SDK"

I have earlier resolved this issue but don't remember how I did it. My other projects are working fine and Android SDK path is correctly specified. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `local.properties` file in your root directory of the Gradle project.

It should contain the path to your Android SDK

```
sdk.dir=/Users/leandros/android-sdk
```

Comment: it already has local.properties file with correct SDK directory.

Answer (score 0):

File Menu > Project Structure > SDK Location.

If you're running an older version of Android Studio, it may be called something other than "SDK Location" in the Project Structure dialog, but it should still be there.